# Output time to a file with the Unix "time" command, but leave the output of the command to the console

Tags: shell, unix, time, io-redirection

I time a command that has some output. I want to output the real time from the time command to a file, but leave the output of the command to the console.

For example, if I do `time my_command` I get this printed in the console:

```
several lines of output from my_command ...
real 1m25.970s
user 0m0.427s
sys 0m0.518s
```

In this case, I want to store only `1m25.970s` to a file, but still print the output of the command to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `time` command is tricky.  The POSIX specification of [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html)
doesn't define the default output format, but does define a format for the `-p` (presumably for 'POSIX') option.  Note the (not easily understood) discussion of command sequences in pipelines.

The Bash specification say `time` prefixes a ['pipeline'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-time), which means that `time cmd1 | cmd2` times both `cmd1` and `cmd2`.  It writes its results to standard error.  The Korn shell is similar.

The POSIX format requires a single space between the tags such as `real` and the time; the default format often uses a tab instead of a space.  Note that the `/usr/bin/time` command may have yet another output format.  It does on macOS, for example, listing 3 times on a single line, by default, with the label after the time value; it supports `-p` to print in an approximation to the POSIX format (but it has multiple spaces between label and time).

You can easily get all the information written to standard error into a file:

```
(time my_command) 2> log.file
```

If `my_command` or any programs it invokes reports any errors to standard error, those will got to the log file too.  And you will get all three lines of the output from `time` written to the file.

If your shell is Bash, you may be able to use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to filter some of the output.

I wouldn't try it with a single command line; the hieroglyphs needed to make it work are ghastly and best encapsulated in shell scripts.

For example, a shell script `time.filter` to capture the output from `time` and write only the `real` time to a log file (default `log.file`, configurable by providing an alternative log file name as the first argument

```
#!/bin/sh

output="${1:-log.file}"
shift
sed -E '/^real[[:space:]]+(([0-9]+m)?[0-9]+[.][0-9]+s?)/{ s//\1/; w '"$output"'
        d;}
        /^(user|sys)[[:space:]]+(([0-9]+m)?[0-9]+[.][0-9]+s?)/d' "$@"
```

This assumes your `sed` uses `-E` to enable extended regular expressions.
The first line of the script finds the line containing the `real` label and the time after it (in a number of possible formats — but not all).  It accepts an optional minutes value such as `60m05.003s`, or just a seconds value `5.00s`, or just `5.0` (POSIX formats — at least one digit after the decimal point is required).  It captures the time part and prints it to the chosen file (by default, `log.file`; you can specify an alternative name as the first argument on the command line). Note that even GNU `sed` treats everything after the `w` command as file name; you have to continue the `d` (delete) command and the close brace `}` on a newline. GNU `sed` does not require the semicolon after `d`; BSD (macOS) `sed` does.  The second line recognizes and deletes the lines reportin the `user` and `sys` times.  Everything else is passed through unaltered.

The script processes any files you give it after the log file name, or standard input if you give it none.  A better command line notation would use an explicit option (`-l logfile`) and `getopts` to specify the log file.

With that in place, we can devise a program that reports to standard error and standard output — `my_command`:

```
echo "nonsense: error: positive numbers are required for argument 1" >&2
dribbler -s 0.4 -r 0.1 -i data -t
echo "apoplexy: unforeseen problems induced temporary amnesia" >&2
```

You could use `cat data` instead of the `dribbler` command.  The `dribbler` command as shown reads lines from `data`, writes them to standard output, with a random delay with a gaussian distribution between lines.  The mean delay is 0.4 seconds; the standard deviation is 0.1 seconds.  The other two lines are pretending to be commands that report errors to standard error.

My `data` file contained a nonsense 'poem' called ['The Great Panjandrum'](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Grand_Panjandrum).

With this background in place, we can run the command and capture the real time in `log.file`, delete (ignore) the user and system time values, while sending the rest of standard error to standard error by using:

```
$ (time my_command) 2> >(tee raw.stderr | time.filter >&2)

nonsense: error: positive numbers are required for argument 1
So she went into the garden
to cut a cabbage-leaf
to make an apple-pie
and at the same time
a great she-bear coming down the street
pops its head into the shop
What no soap
So he died
and she very imprudently married the Barber
and there were present
the Picninnies
and the Joblillies
and the Garyulies
and the great Panjandrum himself
with the little round button at top
and they all fell to playing the game of catch-as-catch-can
till the gunpowder ran out at the heels of their boots
apoplexy: unforeseen problems induced temporary amnesia


$ cat log.file

0m7.278s
```

(The time taken is normally between 6 and 8 seconds.  There are 17 lines, so you'd expect it to take around 6.8 seconds at 0.4 seconds per line.)  The blank line is from `time`; it is pretty hard to remove that blank line, and only that blank line, especially as POSIX says it is optional.  It isn't worth it.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice and detailed answer.

Comment: I have just a follow-up question about the `sed` command. If instead of writing the result to a new `log.file` I would like to append a result to the same file, what changes should I make?

Comment: AFAICS, even the [GNU `sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) doesn’t provide a way of appending to an existing file.  You will need to have `time.filter` write to a new file (`mktemp` command) and concatenate that to the existing file once `sed` completes (and then remove the temporary file, of course).  Beware signals!