# How to deal with the time data

Tags: linux, shell, time

the linux command code `time <command> | tail -n2`, I expect to extract the line of sys time and use time, however,I get this as follows:

`time picat slater-6_sat ver2 "0"`

the Output is :

```
winner = 4 with the least cost = 0

CPU time 0.0 seconds.

success

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.019s
```

while when I only input the `picat slater-6_sat ver2 "0"`

the Output is:

```
winner = 4 with the least cost = 0

CPU time 0.0 seconds.

success
```

I expect input  `time picat slater-6_sat ver2 "0" | tail -n2` ,

the Output is :

```
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.019s
```

however, the truth is :

```
success

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.019s
```

**I guess the reason is the processor think as time ,so treat `picat slater-6_sat ver2 "0"| tail -n2` as the command**

how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```sh
(time picat slater-6_sat ver2 "0") > output.txt 2>&1 && tail -2 output.txt
```

See a similar answer here: [Output time to file with unix "time" command, but leave output of command to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247529/output-time-to-file-with-unix-time-command-but-leave-output-of-command-to-con)

Here's a sample python file:

```py
from time import sleep
for x in range(0,10):
    sleep(0.4)
    print(x)
```

Now run the file like so:

```sh
$ (time python3 test.py) > output.txt 2>&1 && tail -2 output.txt

user    0m0.026s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Additional resources:

- What does `2>&1` do? [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)
- What does `&&` do? https://serverfault.com/questions/53577/linux-bash-syntax-meaning-of-and

Comment: @LibertyAndHappy Absolutely. If you found this answer helpful, I’ll recommend that you put closure to your question by marking it accepted, or wait for other answers and then choose one that’s most acceptable. There’s a check mark by the answer that you can click. Others can then see that this is a solved question and use the question/answer to learn.

Comment: Done,and thanks for teaching me this!